# How do i get this powershell code to work?

Tags: powershell

```
# Printing Test Page
#function TestPage {
#    
#    try {
#       
#         Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName PrintTestPage -InputObject (Get-CimInstance win32_printer -Filter "name = $PrinterName")
#
#        "[+] Test page printed on $PrinterName."
#    
#    } catch{
#   
#        "[X] Unable to print test page on $PrinterName."
#        Write-host "[X] Encountered Error:"$_.Exception.Message
#        
#    }
#}
#
# Duplexing function !! NON FUNCTIONAL !!
#function Duplex {
#
#    try{
#        
#        Write-Host "[+] Enabling Duplexing on $PrinterName"
#
#        Write-Host " "
#    
#        Get-Printer -Name $PrinterName | Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $PrinterName -DuplexingMode TwoSidedLongEdge
#
#        Write-Host " "
#
#        Write-Host "[+] Duplexing Enabled on $PrinterName"
#
#        # Calls the function to print a test page
#        TestPage
#
#    } catch{
#    
#        Write-Host " "
#
#        Write-Host "[X] Failed to enable duplexing on $PrinterName, You may have to enable it in your computer settings."
#
#        Write-host "Encountered Error:"$_.Exception.Message
#
#        Write-Host " "
#
#    }
#}

# Mapping The Printer (Konica)
function MapKonica {

    try{ 

    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Mapping $PrinterName on IP $ip. Please wait..."

    # Maps Printer
    Add-Printer -DriverName "KONICA MINOLTA PS Color Laser Class Driver" -Name $PrinterName -PortName $ip
    
    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Your Konica Minolta has been mapped."

    Write-Host " "

    # Calls the function to set the printer as defualt
    SetDefualt
    } catch {
        
        # Error Handling
        Write-Host "[X] There was an error Mapping your printer. Please make sure you are using the proper IP address and try again"

    }
}

# Mapping The Printer (HP500Class)
function HP500Class {

    try{ 

    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Mapping $PrinterName on IP $ip. Please wait..."

    # Maps Printer
    Add-Printer -DriverName "HP LaserJet Enterprise 500 Color M551 PCL6 Class Driver" -Name $PrinterName -PortName $ip
    
    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Your HP 500 Class has been mapped."

    Write-Host " "

    # Calls the function to set the printer as defualt
    SetDefualt
    } catch {
        
        # Error Handling
        Write-Host "[X] There was an error Mapping your printer. Please make sure you are using the proper IP address and try again"

    }
}

# Mapping The Printer (HPP3015)
function HPP3015 {

    try{ 

    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Mapping $PrinterName on IP $ip. Please wait..."

    # Maps Printer
    Add-Printer -DriverName "HP LaserJet P3011/P3015 PCL6 Class Driver" -Name $PrinterName -PortName $ip
    
    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Your HP P3015 has been mapped."

    Write-Host " "

    # Calls the function to set the printer as defualt
    SetDefualt
    } catch {
        
        # Error Handling
        Write-Host "[X] There was an error Mapping your printer. Please make sure you are using the proper IP address and try again"

    }
}

# Mapping The Printer (HP9000Class)
function HP9000Class {

    try{ 

    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Mapping $PrinterName on IP $ip. Please wait..."

    # Maps Printer
    Add-Printer -DriverName "HP LaserJet P3011/P3015 PCL6 Class Driver" -Name $PrinterName -PortName $ip
    
    Write-Host " "

    Write-Host "[+] Your HP 900 Class has been mapped."

    Write-Host " "

    # Calls the function to set the printer as defualt
    SetDefualt
    } catch {
        
        # Error Handling
        Write-Host "[X] There was an error Mapping your printer. Please make sure you are using the proper IP address and try again"

    }
}

# Printer Input
function PrinterInput {
    $Global:ip = Read-Host -Prompt "[!] Enter the Printer's IP Address: "
    $Global:PrinterName = Read-Host -Prompt "[!] Enter Your Desired Printer Name: "

    # Validate IP Address Format
    $ipRegEx="\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
    if($ip -notmatch $ipRegEx){

        Write-Host "[X] Invalid IP Address"
        Write-Host -NoNewLine '[!] Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        exit
     }
}
```

The above code is the code in question. I am running into errors. Error 1: HP and Konica Minolta do not map. I've never coded in powershell so I've written this code off of stackoverflow snippets and guessing. Lexmark maps and I have that functional but I cannot get it to send a test page to the printers in question. Drivers are all installed on my computer as I work in IT. Error 2: I cannot get any of the functions to send a test page to the printers.

I did 3+ hours of research attempting to find the best way to tackle the things stated above. I have commented out the code for testpage and setting duplexing as neither of those work.

Comment: That's more than 300 lines of code. Do you really expect someone to debug it here? You should boil it down to an [MRE].

Comment: I have made the code as minimal as i believe i can without losing context.

Comment: While I appreciate that you tried I'm afraid your code is still one big mess. It even starts with almost 50 lines of code you commented out.  Each of your *printer map* functions actually only consists of two lines of productive code. The rest is useless `Write-Host` statements or unfunctional `try catch` blocks. I'd recommend to focus on **ONE** issue at a time only. What happens when you run the code for the HP **or** Konica printer? Do you get any error message? If yes - post them here completely (formatted as code please).

Comment: Although I have the drivers installed on my computer, HP gives no errors. Kanico Does not give an error, it runs through the script perfectly but after testing, it is not mapped to my printer.

Answer (score 0):

I cant debug all of your code, but I can give you an example script I wrote to install printers and automatically send a test page after install. Hope it helps

```
function TestCo-installprinter{
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output "Installing the Printer: $printer"
    Get-PrinterPort | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $printer} | Remove-PrinterPort -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Add-PrinterPort -Name $printer -PrinterHostAddress $ip -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Add-Printer -Name $printer -DriverName $driver -PortName $printer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (Get-Printer | Where-Object Name -eq $printer | Where-Object Drivername -eq $driver){
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green

        #Sends a test page to the printer as soon as the printer is installed
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output "Printing a Test Page"
        $printer = [string]$printer
        Start-Sleep 5
        Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName printtestpage -InputObject (Get-CimInstance win32_printer -Filter "name = '$printer'")
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Host "Test page was sent to the printer, please verify" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else{
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Host "Something went wrong" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```